# ksqlDB custom partitioner

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

When I create a stream that processes data and sends them into a topic I want to have control on what partition event is getting on. So is there a way to specify a custom partitioner in KSQL or this feature is not supported at this moment? I think of for example creating a Java class that handles it or specifing certain rules while creating a topic.

Comment: ksqlDB does not support custom partitioners at this point. Feel free to file a GitHub feature request ticket.